# How to calculate rotational velocity from torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

Problem as stated: A radio transmission tower has a mass of 80 kg and is 12 m high. The tower is anchored to the ground by a flexible joint at its base, but it is secured by three cables 120 ∘ apart. In an analysis of a potential failure, a mechanical engineer needs to determine the behavior of the tower if one of the cables broke. The tower would fall away from the broken cable, rotating about its base. [image: figure]

Calculate the speed of the top of the tower as a function of $\theta$.

What I have so far:
$$
T = I\alpha\\
mgsin(\theta)*\frac{L}{2} = \frac{mL^2}{3}\frac{d\omega}{dt}\\
\frac{3}{2}gsin(\theta) = L\frac{d\omega}{dt}\\
$$
Am I supposed to integrate this with respect to $dt$?

**EDIT**
Working with energy, I got
$$
\frac{l}{2}cos(\theta)mg + \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 = \frac{l}{2}mg\\
\frac{2}{3}v^2 = \frac{1}{2}L(1-cos(\theta))g\\
\frac{4}{3}v^2 = L(1-cos(\theta))g\\
v = \sqrt{9(1-cos(\theta))g}
$$
but apparently it's wrong.

Comment: When you calculate the rotational kinetic energy you don't need another $\frac12 mv^2$ term since you used $I$ calculated about the base already. Unless the center of rotation moves you don't need the linear kinetic energy term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it. You would want to express everything in terms of just one variable, otherwise you run into trouble. Right now you have both $\omega$ and $\theta$, but there is a relationship between them...

**However**, since you are asked for an expression in $\theta$, it is simpler to use conservation of energy - you don't actually need to know the time evolution of velocity. You know how much the potential energy of the tower changes with angle, and you know that gets converted to kinetic energy. Here are some of the steps:

Potential energy:

$$PE = mgh = mg\frac{l}{2}\cos\theta$$

Kinetic energy:

$$KE = \frac12 I \omega^2$$

Sum of the two is constant (velocity is zero when $\theta = 0$), so

$$PE + KE = mg\frac{l}{2}$$

Finally, there is a relationship between $\omega$ and $v$, and the solution follows.

Conservation of energy is often the simplest approach.